# Download PDF from remote server using PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fopen, file-get-contents

I'm trying to download a .PDF using PHP. I have used this script a few times to download jpegs but for some reason the PDFs of giving me trouble.

I could manually download these PDFs one by one but it would take ages.

```
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('upc.csv'));
    $count = count($csv) - 1;

    $i = '0';
    while($i <= 2){
    $data_upc = $csv[$i][0];

    $curl = 'site.com'.$data_upc.'#colors';
    $ch = curl_init($curl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);    // No certificate
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);             // Limit redirections to four
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    preg_match('/<a href="\/assets\/hlr-system(.*?)</',$response,$match);

    $pdf_url = $match[1];

    $pdf_url = 'beginning-url'.str_replace('" class="pdf">Spec Sheet','',$pdf_url);

    $pdf = 'brand/'.$data_upc.'.pdf';
    file_put_contents($pdf, fopen($pdf_url));


    echo 'testing: '.$pdf_url;
    echo '<br />';

    $i++;

    }
```

Comment: "it would take ages" what do you mean? What is the problem

Comment: if i was to manually download them one by one. it would take a long time.

Comment: You didnt pass that info but im imaging that you have a list of links in html you want do download, am i right?

Comment: Yes, I'm scraping the page I want and building the link to the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Take this function, loop over it and feed the PDF url.

- `$url` is the full PDF URL
- `$copyPath` is the full path of the new file

The function:

```
function downloadFile($url, $copyPath) {
    $pdf = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents ($copyPath, $pdf);
}
```

### Edit

For example how to loop over the function:

```
$arr[] = 'http://link1';
$arr[] = 'http://link2';
$arr[] = 'http://link3';

$num = 1;
foreach ($arr as $link) {
    downloadFile($url, "file{$num}.pdf");
    $num++;
}

function downloadFile($url, $copyPath) {
    $pdf = file_get_contents($url);
    file_put_contents ($copyPath, $pdf);
}
```

Comment: This didn't work. I got an error saying the function cannot be redeclared.

Comment: I guess you looped over it. Check my Edit

Comment: I guess he has two identical functions

Comment: More like putting the function deceleration within the loop

Comment: There is none and if there is the pdf does not open

Comment: Check that allow_url_fopen=On in the php.ini. If its ok then I don't know. This code works for me.